# Comparing or Diffing Two Graphs in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have two disconnected graphs in a neo4j database. They are very similar networks but one is a version that is several months later of the same graph.

Is there a way that I can easily compare these two graphs to see any additions, deletes or editing that has been done to the network?

Comment: There is some insight here, but not enough to form a complete answer: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-compare-two-graphs-for-equality/

Comment: @joshfindit I agree. Linked page has some problems: given solution only includes nodes (i. e. edges missing) and is not a real comparison but a hashing algorithm. Usually this works despite just hashing, but there may be collisions leading to (rare) false positives (i. e. differing graphs recognized equal). Next is an identity problem, where there is no definition of what to consider equal (identical or equivalent nodes/relationship types). The last 2 missing things are properties of nodes/rels and (maybe) index definitions. And until here this is just equality comparison, still no diffing!

Answer (score 3):

If you want a pure Cypher solution to compare the structure of two graphs you can try the following approach (based on Mark Needham's article for creating adjacency matrices from a graphs https://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/05/20/neo4j-2-0-creating-adjacency-matrices/)

The basic idea is to construct two adjacency matrices, one for each graph to be compared with a column and row for each node identifier (business identifier, not node id), and then to perform some algebra on the two matrices to find the differences.

The problem is that if the graphs don't contain the same node identifiers then the adjacency matrices will have different dimensions, making the actual comparison harder, so the trick is to produce two identically sized matrices and populate one with the adjacency matrix from the first graph and the second with the adjacency matrix from the second graph.

Consider these two graphs:

[image: Two similar graphs]

All the nodes in Graph 1 are labeled `:G1` and all the nodes in Graph 2 are labeled `:G2`.

Step 1 is to find all the unique node identifiers, the 'name' property in this case, from both graphs:

```
match (g:G1)
with collect(g.name) as g1Names
match (g:G2)
with g1Names + collect(g.name) as collectedNames
unwind collectedNames as allNames
with collect(distinct allNames) as uniqueNames
```

`uniqueNames` now contains a list of all the unique identifiers in both graphs. (It is necessary to unwind the collected names and then collect them back up because the distinct operator doesn't work on a list - there is a lot more collecting and unwinding to come!)

Next, two new lists of unique identifiers are created to represent the two dimensions of of the adjacency matrix for the first graph.

```
unwind uniqueNames as dim1
unwind uniqueNames as dim2
```

Then an optional match is performed to create a Cartesian product of each node with every other node in `G1`, the first graph.

```
optional match p = (g1:G1 {name: dim1})-->(g2:G1 {name: dim2})
```

The matched paths will either exist or return null from the above match statement. These are now converted into a count of edges between nodes or a zero if there was no connection (the essence of the adjacency matrix). The matched paths are sorted to keep the order of rows and columns in the matrix correct when it is created. `uniqueNames` is passed through as it will be used to construct the adjacency matrix for the second graph.

```
with uniqueNames, dim1, dim2, case when p is null then 0 else count(p) end as edgeCount
order by dim1, dim2
```

Next, the edges are rolled up into a list of values for the second dimension

```
with uniqueNames, dim1 as g1DimNames, collect(edgeCount) as g1Matrix
order by g1DimNames
```

The whole operation above is repeated for the second graph to generate the second adjacency matrix.

```
with uniqueNames, g1DimNames, g1Matrix
unwind uniqueNames as dim1
unwind uniqueNames as dim2
optional match p = (g1:G2 {name: dim1})-->(g2:G2 {name: dim2})
with g1DimNames, g1Matrix, dim1, dim2, case when p is null then 0 else count(p) end as edges
order by dim1, dim2
with g1DimNames, g1Matrix, dim1 as g2DimNames, collect(edges) as g2Matrix
order by g1DimNames, g2DimNames
```

At this point `g1DimNames` and `g1Matrix` form a Cartesian product with the `g2DimNames` and `g2Matrix`. This product is factored by removing duplicate rows with the filter statement

```
with filter( x in collect([g1DimNames, g1Matrix, g2DimNames, g2Matrix]) where x[0] = x[2]) as factored
```

The final step is to determine the differences between the two matrices, which is just a matter of finding the rows which are different in the factored result above.

```
with  filter(x in factored where x[1] <> x[3]) as diffs
unwind diffs as result
return result
```

We then end up with a result that shows what is different and how:

[image: Result set]

To interpret the results: The first two columns represent a subset of the first graph's adjacency matrix and the second two columns represent the corresponding row by row adjacency matrix for the second graph. The alpha characters represent the node names and the lists of digits represent the corresponding rows in the matrix for each original column, A to G in this case.

Looking at the "A" row, we can conclude node "A" owns nodes "B" and "C" in graph 1 and node "A" owns node "B" once and node "C" twice in graph 2.

For the "D" row, node "D" does not own any nodes in graph 1 and owns nodes "F" and "G" in graph 2.

There are at least a couple of caveats to this approach:

1. Creating Cartesian products is slow, in even small graphs. (I have
   been comparing XML schemas with this technique and comparing two
   graphs containing about 200 nodes each takes around 30 seconds,
   compared with 14ms for the example above, on my fairly modestly
   sized server).
2. Reading the result matrix is not easy when there are more than a
   trivial amount of nodes as it is hard to keep track of which column
   corresponds to which node. (To get round this, I have exported the
   results to a csv and then inserted the node names (from `uniqueNames`)
   into the top row of the spreadsheet.

Comment: I suspect this may not be sufficient to handle different relationship types, just the number of relationships. For this approach you may even have to go one dimension up to kind of a adjacency tensor of rank 3 to distinguish between the relationship types. So the adjacency lists would not only contain a relationship number but would have to be extended to lists of relationship numbers for each relationship type. But the basic idea behind it is very promising.

Comment: I mean 3rd-order tensor. Sorry, can't edit the previous comment any more.

Comment: A good point Chris. I'll be reviewing this technique again soon, so I'll have a look at relationship names then.

Answer (score 2):

While this may be an older question that might no longer concern the original inquirer, I'd like to provide an answer in case it proves valuable to anyone who comes across it.

If you read the responses to all the provided answers, you’ll notice each of the answers fall short of providing truly practical solutions because they all have significant issues. They either compare subgraphs within a single database instead of comparing 2 different databases or run into complexities due to the implementation choices of existing export tools.

Compare41 is a tool that can compare two neo4j databases. You can see the difference in their model, difference in the actual data and synch a subgraph or the whole database. It can be found at [https://www.circles-arrows.com/](https://www.circlesarrows.com/).

For full transparency, I created Compare41 and have a close affiliation with Circles Arrows.

Answer (score 1):

I guess diffing is most easy done using a text based tool.

One approach I can think of is to export the two subgraphs to GraphML using https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools and then apply the regular `diff` from unix.

Another one would be using [`dump` in neo4j-shell](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/shell-commands.html#_dumping_the_database_or_a_cypher_result_to_cypher_statements) and diff the results as above.

Comment: Having tried similar things myself, I will share the main reason why this doesn't work: the tools that export from Neo4j have no need to consider the order of the nodes and relationships in the output file. Plain-text-diffing these files produces a huge number of false changes as the two files are almost always in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

This largely depends on what you want the diff to be of and the constraints of the graphs themselves.

- If nodes and relationships have an identifier property (not the internal Neo4j ID), then you could just pull down the nodes and relationships of each graph and track which are added, removed, or changed (diff the properties).
- If relationships are not uniquely identified (by a property), but nodes are, their *natural key* is the start node, end node and type since duplicate relationships cannot exist.
- If neither have managed identifiers, but properties are immutable, then those could be compared across nodes (could be costly), then subsequently the relationships in method.